# Can we keep approvals for when specific task failed in build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, conditional-statements

In my build pipeline i have dot net test task it's failing for some reason i add a condition for this .build we be rum but in release can i keep any approval it's should ask for approval to run the dev environment is this possible please let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Not sure I get it, do you want to have an approval stage/step when a build fails before a release?

Comment: I mean when my test case failed in build i already add condition to run job even it's failed 
 in release pipeline it should ask for approval to deploy into the environment it should ask approval only when it failed not everytime